# A few questions about $E_6$ and its symmetric spaces

Tags: lie-groups, symmetric-spaces, exceptional-groups

**Preface**
The purpose of my question - on high level - is to understand exceptional symmetric spaces. My latest idea is to embed them into Lie group. There is quite nice [embedding](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248763/conjugacy-classes-of-involutions-in-compact-simple-lie-group) of 32-dimensional $E_{III}$ and 40-dimensional $E_{II}$ in $E_6$. It would be nice to see similar embedding for $E_I$ and $E_{IV}$.

Another thing which strikes me is that symmetric spaces $E_I$, $E_{II}$, $E_{III}$, $E_{IV}$ correspond to 2-dimensional projective space over $\mathbb C \otimes \mathbb O$. Can we analyze 1-dimensional space over this algebra ? In such case we obtain symmetric spaces $G_{5,5}^+\times S^1$, $G_{4,6}^+$, $G_{2,8}^+$, $S^9\times S^1$. These conlusion I present without proof. The dimensions of last symmetric spaces are lower by 16 than the first ones. Can we see the same analogy when considering symmetric spaces corresponding to $\mathbb C \subset \mathbb H$ ? I am asking, because on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space#Classification_result) wikipedia page symmetric space $E_{II}$ is presented as "space of symmetric subspaces isometric to $\mathbb C\otimes \mathbb HP^2$" (which is $G_{2,4}\mathbb C$ according to me).

As a last statement in my preface I would like to add that I am not interested in abstract definitions. I look at Lie groups as matrix groups preferably. I also accept Lie group as group acting on some geometrical object called "Rosenfeld projective plane". (*It seems this term is not accepted by all mathematical community*). Therefore I would preferably see embedding of symmetric space in Lie group $E_6$ in this language.

**Formulating the questions**

> **Question 1** Is it possible to embed symmetric spaces 42-dimensional $E_I$ and 26-dimensional $E_{IV}$ into compact Lie group $E_6$ ? Please provide construction of such embedding.

As it was answered in this [Conjugacy classes of involutions in compact simple Lie group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248763/conjugacy-classes-of-involutions-in-compact-simple-lie-group) question, $E_{II}$ and $E_{III}$ can be embedded in $E_6$ as components if $\{x^2=1\}$ set.

Next I would like to continue in $Spin_{10}\times Spin_2$ group considered as automorphism of $\mathbb C\otimes \mathbb OP^1$. The plan is to find nice embeddding of $E_{IV}$ in $E_6$ first.
Define nine letters in Clifford algebra $C_9$. Let $e_k$=$$\begin{pmatrix} L_k & \\
& R_k \end{pmatrix}
$$ where $L_k$ and $R_k$ are left and right multiplications by imaginary base octonions, k=1..7.
Let $e_8$=$$\begin{pmatrix} & S \\
-S &   \end{pmatrix}
$$ and $ e_9$=$$\begin{pmatrix} & iS \\
iS &   \end{pmatrix}
$$. $S$ is octonion conjugation. Let $V_{10}$=$<1,e_1,...,e_9>$ and $S^9$ be unit sphere in $V_{10}$.

Let $E_{III}^1$ = $\{iv\bar w: v\perp w \in S^9 \}$. It can be treated as $P^1$ (shortcut for $\mathbb C \otimes \mathbb OP^1$). Note that elements of this set does not depend on selection of $v,w$ from given plane of $V_{10}$. So $P^1$=$G_{2,8}^+$ topologically. In this definition $i$=$e_1...e_9$ is center of Clifford algebra $C_9$.
Products of perpendicular elements from $P^1$ is set $E_{II}^1$=$E_{II}\cap P^1$=$\{v\bar wx\bar y: v\perp w\perp x \perp y \in S^9 \}$=$G_{4,6}^+$.
The dimension of $E_*^1$ is 16 less then dimension of $E_*$ where *=I,II,III,IV.

The candidate for $E_I^1$ is $G_{5,5}^+\times S^1$, $E_{IV}^1$=$S^9\times S^1$.
To start the prove let's ask question.

> **Question 2:** Can $S^9$ be treated as embedding of $Spin_{10}/Spin_9$ into $Spin_{10}$ ?

To analyze dimension problem let's ask following question.

> **Question 3:** Is dimension of $\{\mathbb CP^1\subset\mathbb HP^1\}$ four dimensions lower than $\{\mathbb CP^2\subset\mathbb HP^2\}$ ?

The first space seems to be 6-dimensional $G_{2,3}$. I don't know dimension of second space (please help), but it should be 10-dimensional $:)$

**EDIT:** Thank you for re-opening my question. Using first comment from Robert Bryant I will answer my first question. The Cartan's embedding uses outer involution. However I would like to find out more about the geometry before I post the answer. It will add more flavor to the answer. 
I might post similar questions for $E_7$ and $E_8$. Again I need to understand more the geometry.

**EDIT October 2016**
I paste following pictures illustrating at least how dimensions of exceptional symmetric spaces and corresponding maximal subgroups can be calculated. I hope there is more in the pictures. I leave the reader to figure out what they contain. First picture show compact $E_6$ and $E_{II}$

[image: Compact $E_6$ and $E_{II}$]

and remaining $E_{IV}$, $E_I$, $E_{III}$.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Cartan showed that every (irreducible) symmetric space can be isometrically embedded (up to a constant factor) into its group of symmetries.  Moreover, this embedding is canonical:  Let $\sigma:G\to G$ be the involution whose fixed subgroup is $K\subset G$, then the symmetric space $G/K$ has an embedding $\iota:G/K\to G$ given by $\iota(gK) = g\sigma(g)^{-1}$.  This $\iota$ is equivariant with respect to the left $G$-action and isometric when $G$ is given its bi-invariant metric (with the appropriate constant scale factor).

Comment: I have asked, because on my previous question Mikhail Borovoi commented that EI and EIV cannot be embedded into $E_6$ as G-subvarieties. So posted this question to see the answer. I have not finished my question, because  I planned to add some proposal, how EI and EIV could be embedded into $E_6$. I would like to see it in whole "magic square" picture. It is nice to hear that Cartan already embedded symmetric spaces into its group of symmetric. In such case I would like to see some nice embeddings as there are such for EII and EIII.

Comment: @RobertBryant: I don't think that your embedding $\iota$ is equivariant with respect to the left $G$-action.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi:  What do you mean, 'not equivariant'?  The embedding $\iota$ satisfies $$\iota\bigl(h(gK)\bigr) = h\,\iota(gK)\,\sigma(h)^{-1}$$ for all $h,g\in G$, so it intertwines the left action of $G$ on $G/K$ with the $\sigma$-twisted conjugate action of $G$ on itself in the range.  Meanwhile, the $\sigma$-twisted conjugate action is clearly isometric with respect to the bi-invariant metric on $G$, so the embedding $\iota$ is certainly isometric (up to a constant scale factor, which can be taken to be $1$).

Comment: @RobertBryant: Going back to Cartan. Can we find $\sigma$ which fix subgroup $Sp_4$ or $F_4$ of $E_6$ ?

Comment: @RobertBryant: You are right, your (Catan's) embedding is equivariant with respect to the canonical action of $G$ on $G/K$ and the *$\sigma$-twisted conjugate* action of $G$ on $G$.

Comment: @RobertBryant: On the other hand, if the involution $\sigma$ is *inner*, $\sigma={\rm inn}(x)$ for some $x\in G$, then we have an embedding $j\colon G/H\hookrightarrow G$ given by $j(gK)=gx$. For this embedding we have $$j(h\cdot gK)=h\cdot j(gK)$$  for all $h,g\in G$, i.e., the embedding $j$ is equivariant with respect to the canonical action of $G$ on $G/K$ and the *action  by left translations* of $G$ on $G$. Such an embedding is impossible when $\sigma$ is outer.

Comment: @MarekMitros: Concerning your question to Robert: Yes, there are such $\sigma$ (they exist for any symmetric space, it is an alternative definition of a symmetric space). A description of $\sigma$ for all symmetric spaces in terms of affine Dynkin diagrams can be found, for example, in Table 7 of the book by Onishchik and Vinberg. You can define $E_6$ explicitely, then it would be nice to construct the subgroups $C_4$ and $F_4$ of $E_6$ explicitly....

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, Thank you, Michail ! I will look for Vinberg, Oniszczik book. Can this $\sigma$
 be obtained by complex conjugation and map $x\rightarrow \tilde x$
 which fix quaternion subalgebra in octonions for $\mathbb C \otimes \mathbb O$ ? I will think more and I will post answer to my question which is close to be closed :-)

Comment: @MarekMitros: Try to clarify your question. Indeed, it is not clear what you are asking....

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, I tried to clarify. Can you please vote to reopen ? *I hope that such campaign for reopening the question is legal here ;)*

Comment: @MarekMitros: Robert Bryant has answered your Question 1 in his comment.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: In such case can you or Robert Bryant post the answer with definition of $\sigma$ involutive automorphism of $E_6$ which fix subgroup $F_4$ ? I prefer to look at Lie group as matrix group. Say that for standard $E_6$ representation in $\mathbb C^{27}$ I define $\sigma$ as complex conjugation. I such case $F_4$ is fixed, because it is subset of real matrices in $E_6$. What is remaining to prove:
1) is it homorphism
2) is the image inside $E_6$
3) How to find $E_{IV}$ in my matrix $E_6$ using Robert's definition $\iota(gK)=g\sigma(g)^{-1}$

Comment: @RobertBryant: The formula $\iota(gK)=g\sigma(g)^{-1}$ defines embeding of $E_{IV}$ into **automorphism group** of $E_6$. What is automorphism group of $E_6$ ?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi:  Your $j$ (which is supposed to be equivariant w.r.t. the usual left action of $G$ on the domain and range) has the problem that it is not well defined:  $j(gK) = gx$ cannot work because we can have $gK = hK$ without having $gx = hx$, as long as $K$ is nontrivial.  Instead what you probably meant was to use $j(gK) = gxg^{-1}$, which does work if $\sigma(g) = xgx^{-1}$ defines an (inner) involution that has $K$ as its fixed subgroup.  Then the map $j$ is well-defined at least, but it is now not $G$-equivariant unless you use the left action of $G$ by conjugation on the range.

Comment: @MarekMitros: The formula that I gave (which, I remind you, is due to Cartan, not me) for $\iota$ embeds $G/K$ into $G$, not $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$.  It is defined *using* $\sigma$, which is an element of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ that need not be an inner automorphism.   When $\mathrm{E}_6$ is the compact real form of $\mathrm{E}_6^\mathbb{C}\subset\mathrm{GL}(27,\mathbb{C})$ (which has a center isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$),  $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{E}_6)$ has two components, and there are $5$ components of the locus consisting of elements $\sigma\in\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{E}_6)$ satisfying $\sigma^2=1$.

Comment: @RobertBryant: It is interesting, what you say in last sentence about 5 components. Now I understood that in Cartan's formula $\iota(gK)=g\sigma(g)^{-1}$ element $\sigma(g)$ is group element !! Indeed if we take $gk$ then $gk\sigma(k)^{-1}\sigma(g)^{-1}=g\sigma(g)^{-1}$, because $\sigma$ fix $K$.

Comment: @MarekMitros: Yes, your understanding of the formula is correct, and it's now clear to you that $\iota$ maps $G/K$ into $G$, not $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$. (Your comment suggested otherwise.) As for $\mathrm{E}_6$, yes, $$ \mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{E}_6) = \mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{E}_6)^0\cup \mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{E}_6)^1$$ has two components, and the locus consisting of the elements $\sigma$ such that $\sigma^2=1$ has three components in $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{E}_6)^0$ (the identity component, i.e., the inner automorphisms) and two components in $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{E}_6)^1$ (the properly outer automorphisms).

Comment: @RobertBryant: You are right! You understood correctly what I really meant! I meant the action of $G$ on itself by conjugation.

Comment: @MarekMitros: All these $\sigma$ mentioned by Robert are naturally described in terms of the Dynkin diagram of $E_6$. For example, $\sigma$ corresponding to $EIV$ is described as follows: You take the Dynkin diagram $D$ of type $E_6$ (see Wikipedia), it has a unique nontrivial automorphism $\tau$, it is of order 2. Since the Lie algebra of $G$ can be constructed from the Dynkin diagram  $D$ using generators and relations, you obtain induced involutions  of ${\rm Lie}(G)$ and of $G$. This involution of $G$ corresponds to $EIV$.

Comment: @MarekMitros: If you want to get a matrix realization of $\sigma$ corresponding to $EIV$, you can try to compute the root decomposition in your matrix realization of $E_6$, and then compute the $\sigma$ corresponding to the nontrivial automorphism $\tau$ of the Dynkin diagram. Alternatively, you can try to ask a separate question about that (say, about the root decomposition and a system of simple roots in your matrix realization of $E_6$). Hopefully you will get a reference. Try to explain very clearly what you are asking!  Good luck!

Comment: @MarekMitros: Or  you can ask a separate question, asking to describe the  involution  $\sigma$ of $E_6$ with the subgroup of fixed points $F_4$ *in your matrix realization*. After you know $\sigma$, Cartan's formula gives you an embedding of the symmetric space into $G$.

Comment: Let $a$ be involution in $E_6$ which preserve $SU_6\times SU_2$. From Cartan formula we conclude that set
$M$=$\{gag^{-1}a: g \in E_6\}$ is equal to $E_{II}$. Is the element $gag^{-1}a$ involution ? Not necessary.
I prefer to look at the conjugacy class of involutions $N$=$\{gag^{-1}\}$ which is equal to $E_{II}$. Indeed $N=Ma$, so both sets are topologically the same.
Is this correct reasoning ?

Comment: @MarekMitros: Yes, this is correct. Note that the symmetric space has not only a topology. It is a manifold with a Riemann metric. Again, $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic Riemann manifolds.

Comment: @MarekMitros: This works also for $EI$ and $EIV$: you consider $\{\bar g\sigma\bar g^{-1}\ :\ g\in G\}$, but now $\bar g\sigma\bar g^{-1}\in {\rm Aut\ }G$. Here $\bar g$ denotes the inner automorphism of $G$ defined by $g$. Note that ${\rm Aut\ }G={\rm Aut}({\rm Lie\ }G)$, so it is a matrix group, and it  contains $G/Z(G)$ as a subgroup of index 2. As Robert has written, you get $EI$ and $EIV$ as conjugacy classes of of involutions, but they are not involutions *in* $G$, they are involutions *of* $G$ (outer involutive automorphisms of $G$ and of ${\rm Lie}\ G$).

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: thank you! To summarize, I have two SS in F4, both reprezented as cc of involutions. $F_I$ elements are obtained as products of four elements from $F_{II}$=$OP^2$. $F_I$ corresponds to $\tilde O$. In $E_6$ we have four SSs. $E_{II}$, $E_{IV}$, $E_I$ correspond to $C\otimes \tilde O$, $\tilde C\otimes O$, $\tilde C\otimes \tilde O$ respectively. $E_{II}$ elements are products of two elements from $E_{III}$.

Comment: In $E_7$ there are three SSs. $E_V$ and $E_{VII}$ are obtained by outer automorphisms of $E_7$, it seems . On the other hand there are no symmetries in Dynkin diagram of E7 ?!  Are there any outer automorphisms, then ? In $E_8$ I am hoping that product of two elements from $E_{IX}$ gives elements from $E_{VIII}$ and there are no outer automorphisms.

Comment: It seems in $E_7$ there are no outer automorphisms, so we should expect that all three ESS are represented as conjugacy classes of involutions there. I need good model of $E_7$. Lately I found Yokota paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.0431 and there are a lot of usefull information about exceptional Lie groups. $E_7$ and $E_8$ are defined there using Freudenthal constructions. I prefer to work with 28-dimensional quaternion representation of $E_7$.

Comment: @MarekMitros: Indeed, the Dynkin diagram of $E_7$ has no nontrivial automorphisms (look at it in Wikipedia!), and therefore $E_7$ has no outer automorphisms. The same refers also to $A_1,\ B_n,\ C_n$, $E_8$, $F_4$ and $G_2$ - you can check this yourself in 3 minutes! There are outer automorphisms only for $A_n$  $(n>1)$, $D_n$, and $E_6$.