# Embedding of Riemannian symmetric spaces $E_I$ and $E_{IV}$ into Lie group $E_6$

Tags: lie-groups, spin-geometry, symmetric-spaces

In answer and comments to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248763/conjugacy-classes-of-involutions-in-compact-simple-lie-group) mathoverflow question we have discussed possiblity of embedding Riemmanian symmetric spaces $E_I, E_{II}, E_{III},E_{IV}$ of dimension $42,40,32,26$ respectively into $E_6$ Lie group. Spaces $E_{II}$ and $E_{III}$ can be embedded as set $M=\{x^2=1\}$ having $12$ and $16$ dimensions of eigenspaces with eigenvalue $-1$. Consider set $P=\{x^2 \in E_{III}\}$ in Lie group $E_6$. Is there chance to find $E_I$ or $E_{IV}$ in $P$ ?

The hint is $Spin_{10}$ subgroup and grassmanians which can be found in set $\{x^2=-1\}$ in Clifford algebra.

This is duplicate question of the [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084556/embedding-of-riemannian-symmetric-spaces-e-i-and-e-iv-into-e-6-lie-group) on math.stackexchange.